# How to copy the current line to the clipboard via keyboard

Tags: iterm2

Iterm has a couple of different options to allow you to select text, copy mode and by adding custom key combinations.  I don't seem to be able to configure it to do what I want in a simple way, however.  I mainly need this to copy the current bash line to the clipboard.  I would like my workflow to be like this:

Press ctrl-a to get the begining of the line.
Press something like cmd+shift+right_arrow to select what's on the current line
Press cmd-c to copy

What specifically do I need to change within iterm to get a similar setup?

Answer (score 5):

Using iterm2 with vim mode. OS: macOS. In my case, to resolve this issue you may press:
shift+cmd+c. Then the cursor will change its view. You'll notice this. And after this, you'll be able to navigate in a vim, command mode:
press `v` to go for select mode and after this move over the current line of code via 'h' and 'l' keys (using or note 'shift').

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled [Shell Integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html):

1. Press `Home` to go to line beginning
2. Type `echo` and `Enter` so that current line in printed as output
3. Press `Cmd-Shift-A` to select last command output
4. `Cmd-C` to copy to clipboard.